# Xcode - open more than 1 project in Groups & Files?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible in XCode to open several projects in one window like in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Workspace to open multiple projects but it is generally meant to be used for projects that are similar or used together. These projects will share a build directory. This is as close as you can get in Xcode to what Eclipse does.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So as I understand - NO.
WTF?